# React js show/hide specific element using Material UI checkbox's state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

hello I'm trying to show and hide specific elements with checkbox material and what is happening now is when one checkbox is checked all the hidden divs are showing up.

You can see the problem here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1ecdqb?file=demo.tsx

edit: I know that I need more variables in the state but I ask if there is a way to do it without state for each checkbox because there are gonna be 10 more checkboxes

```
 const UninstallView = () => {
        const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

        const handleChange = event => {
            if (event.target.checked) {
                setIsChecked(true);
                }
            else {
                setIsChecked(false);
                }
            }
    return (
    <div>
 <FormGroup>
    <FormControlLabel  control={<Checkbox  onChange={handleChange}   />} label="simple isn't what I expected" />
       {isChecked ? <TextField
                    id="filled-multiline-static"
                    label="What did you expect from simple?"
                    multiline
                    rows={4}
                    defaultValue=""
                    variant="filled"
                    />
                    : '' }
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
           <FormControlLabel  control={<Checkbox  onChange={handleChange}  />} label="simple isn't working correctly" />
               {isChecked ? 
                   <div>
                        <h1>hello</h1>
                    </div>
                       : '' }
                </FormGroup>
    </div>
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sharing 1 state across 2 checkboxes. You should have a separate state that holds the state for each checkbox.

This code may help:

```js
const UninstallView = () => {
    const [isFirstChecked, setIsFirstChecked] = useState(false);
    const [isSecondChecked, setIsSecondChecked] = useState(false);

    return (<div>
        <FormGroup>
            <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox onChange={() => setIsFirstChecked(!isFirstChecked)}/>}
                label="simple isn't what I expected"/>
            {isFirstChecked ? <TextField
                id="filled-multiline-static"
                label="What did you expect from simple?"
                multiline
                rows={4}
                defaultValue=""
                variant="filled"
            /> : ''}
        </FormGroup>
        <FormGroup>
            <FormControlLabel
                control={<Checkbox onChange={() => setIsSecondChecked(!isSecondChecked)}/>}
                label="simple isn't working correctly"/>
            {isSecondChecked ? <div>
                <h1>hello</h1>
            </div> : ''}
        </FormGroup>
    </div>);
}
```

[Sandbox example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1ecdqb-gtf8gk?file=demo.tsx)

Comment: the problem is that are gonna be 10 more checkboxes and I don't want to make a state for every check box

Comment: Since you are using the "state" of these checkboxes to conditonally show something on the screen, you need to store their current state somewhere within your component. You can have separate state variables for each or you can have a single state variable that hosts an array of key-value pairs with each pair's key being the name or id and the value being the current boolean state (checked-unchecked) of each checkbox.